# *ngFor doesn't work for me on Angular 2

Tags: angular, webstorm, ngfor

I'm new with Angular. I'm trying to make a table with information on videos.
I'm working with Angular 2 using WebStorm IDE.

When I load the project, it just write "Loading...".

The problem with the code is with the `*ngFor`, because if I take it down, I see an empty table (at least I see something).

I wrote the `*ngfor` like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let v of fevVidoes">
```

As I understand, this is the new format, for `ngfor`.

but if I write:

```
<tr *ngFor="#v of fevVidoes">
```

I get an error from WebStorm about the format ("statement unexpected"), BUT when I load the project, it doesn't show me "Loading...", it just show me an empty table.

I downloaded and installed Angular yesterday, and I have all the latest versions.

This is my source code:

### playlist.component.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let v of fevVidoes">
            <td>{{v.id}}</td>
            <td>{{v.title}}</td>
            <td>{{v.desc}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### playlist.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'playlist',
    templateUrl: 'app/ts/playlist.component.html',
    inputs: ['fevVideos']

})

export class PlaylistComponent{}
```

### app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Config} from './config.service';
import {Video} from './video';
import {PlaylistComponent} from './playlist.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/ts/app.component.html',
    directives: [PlaylistComponent]

})



export class AppComponent {

    mainHeading = Config.MAIN_HEADING;

    fevVidoes:Array<Video>;

    constructor()
    {
        this.fevVidoes = [
            new Video(1, "MACKLEMORE & RYAN LEWIS - THRIFT SHOP FEAT. WANZ (OFFICIAL VIDEO)", "QK8mJJJvaes", "MACKLEMORE & RYAN LEWIS - THRIFT SHOP FEAT. WANZ (OFFICIAL VIDEO)"),
            new Video(2, "OneRepublic - Apologize  Stay With Me (Pinkpop)", "SVQz6xGCTKM", "OneRepublic LIVE SHOW - Apologize  Stay With Me (Pinkpop)")
                    ]
    }
}
```

### video.ts

```
export class Video
{
    id:number;
    title:string;
    videoCode:string;
    desc:string;

    constructor(id:number,title:string,videoCode:string,desc:string)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.videoCode = videoCode;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<h1> {{ mainHeading }} </h1>
<playlist [fevVideos] = "fevVidoes"></playlist>
```

Comment: Forget about `<tr *ngFor="#v of fevVidoes">`, is was only valid in 2.0.0-beta.x and older.

Comment: Please check the docs on angular.io. As @echonax mentioned in a comment to my answer `import {Component} from 'angular2/core';` is also invalid in released angular versions (longer than a year back).

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'playlist',
    templateUrl: 'app/ts/playlist.component.html',
    inputs: ['fevVideos']
})
export class PlaylistComponent{}
```

should be

```
@Component({
    selector: 'playlist',
    templateUrl: 'app/ts/playlist.component.html',
})
export class PlaylistComponent{
  @Input() fevVideos;
}
```

This line has a typo

```
this.fevVidoes = [
```

should be

```
this.fevVideos = [
```

Comment: Günter, if you check the imports `import {Component} from 'angular2/core';` they are the beta version imports. There's a confusion with the versions I think :-)